# Sort a list in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I receive an array of sport events like that in a component :

```
[{ ligue: "champions league", event: "psg - varsovia", scoreteam1: 1, scoreteam:2},{ ligue: "world cup", event: "belgium - england", scoreteam1: 1, scoreteam:2},{ ligue: "champions league", event: "madrid - fc bruge", scoreteam1: 3, scoreteam:2},{ ligue: "champions league", event: "milan - dortmund", scoreteam1: 1, scoreteam:2},{ ligue: "world cup", event: "japan - danemark", scoreteam1: 1, scoreteam:5}]
```

And i would like to get a list of all events for the "ligue" like that:

Champions league:
*psg - varsovia
*madrid - fc bruge
*milan - dortmund

World cup:
*belgium - england
*japan - danemark

for now i loop over my soccerlist like that so each time i repeat the name of the "ligue":

```
<section v-for="(loop,i) in soccerlist" :key="i" ><header>  {{ loop.ligue }}</header><div> {{loop.event}} {{ loop.scoreteam1 }} {{ loop.scoreteam2 }}</section>
```

so i want to have all matches from a "ligue", how can i do that with vue js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably better off using a `computed` property to sort your array into leagues. For example:

```
computed: {
  sortedGames() {
    return this.soccerlist.reduce((acc, game) => {
      if (acc[game.ligue]) acc[game.ligue].push(game);
      else acc[game.ligue] = [game];
      return acc;
    }, {})
  }
}
```

This will return you an object, with each game grouped by `ligue`. You can then `v-for="ligue in sortedGames"` and go from there.